# android 6.0 can not write external sdcard

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sdcard

Not able to write file to external SDCard in Android v6.0.1. 
Tested on Device: Redmi Note3

I've already have write permission using:

```
@TargetApi(21)
public void requestDocumentPermission() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SDCardBrowser.REQUEST_DOCUMENTS);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DOCUMENTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { // given permission
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        takeUriPermission(data.getFlags(), uri);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.PREFS_DEFAULT_URI, uri.toString()).apply();
        doCopy(selectedNodes, toNode);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And here is my copy method below, it runs normally but i didn't find target file in target dictionary. Whom ever meet this question? Help me plz.

```
@TargetApi(23)
public static void copyFileV23(File srcFile, File destFile) {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    Context context = XXXApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String strUri = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(Constants.PREFS_DEFAULT_URI, null);
    if (null == strUri) {
        return;
    }
    DocumentFile rootDocument = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(strUri));

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
        DocumentFile target = find(destFile.getAbsolutePath(), rootDocument, getMimeType(srcFile));
        out = resolver.openOutputStream(target.getUri());

        if (null != out) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
        }
    }
}

private static DocumentFile find(String absolutePath, DocumentFile root, String mime) {
    if (null == root || null == absolutePath) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] paths = absolutePath.split("\\/");
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        if (paths[i].equals(""))
            continue;

        DocumentFile documentFile = root.findFile(paths[i]);

        if (null == documentFile) {
            if (i < paths.length - 1) {
                documentFile = root.createDirectory(paths[i]);
            } else {
                documentFile = root.createFile(mime, paths[i]);
            }
        }
        root = documentFile;
    }
    return root;
}
```

**Edit-1**
Find solution, `find()` method incorrect. It should be like this below:

```
private static DocumentFile findFileInExternal(String absolutePath, DocumentFile root, String mime) {
    if (null == root || null == absolutePath) {
        return null;
    }

    String externalPath = ExternalStorage.getStoragePath(true);
    if (null == externalPath) {
        return null;
    }
    absolutePath = absolutePath.substring(externalPath.length());

    String[] paths = absolutePath.split("\\/");
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        if (paths[i].equals(""))
            continue;

        DocumentFile documentFile = root.findFile(paths[i]);

        if (null == documentFile) {
            if (i < paths.length - 1) {
                documentFile = root.createDirectory(paths[i]);
            } else {
                documentFile = root.createFile(mime, paths[i]);
            }
        }

        root = documentFile;
    }

    return root;
}
```

Comment: If your `find` method is the one that isn't working, you should include that method in your question.

Comment: @ianhanniballake maybe you didn't saw it bro, scroll down in code area you will see `find()` method posted :-)

Comment: Check your app info --> Permission for double sure if you have it or not.

Comment: Already check for many times, PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission returns GRANTED, and app info --> Permission also granted. Only `DocumentFile` can write external sdcard in android6.0?

Answer (score 0):

`find()` method is wrong. I should delete external sdcard path before i do `split` operation. Or it will add external sdcard path twice. Here is the correct `find()` method below:

```
private static DocumentFile find(String absolutePath, DocumentFile root, String mime) {
    if (null == root || null == absolutePath) {
        return null;
    }

    String externalPath = ExternalStorage.getStoragePath(true);
    if (null == externalPath) {
        return null;
    }
    absolutePath = absolutePath.substring(externalPath.length());

    String[] paths = absolutePath.split("\\/");
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        if (paths[i].equals(""))
            continue;

        DocumentFile documentFile = root.findFile(paths[i]);

        if (null == documentFile) {
            if (i < paths.length - 1) {
                documentFile = root.createDirectory(paths[i]);
            } else {
                documentFile = root.createFile(mime, paths[i]);
            }
        }

        root = documentFile;
    }

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `getExternalFilesDirs()`. It will tell you two paths where you can write files to. The second one is for the removable micro SD card.

Apps can only write to an app specific directory on the card.

Google allows it. But now you have to see if your manufacturer implemented it.

The funny thing of this restriction is that you dont need the usual write and read permissions for those directories.

Comment: but i need write file 2 external sdcard, i've already tested `file.mkdir` cannot create dictionary successfully at external-path get by `getExternalFilesDirs()`.

Comment: Then you now know that the manufacturer is restricting this. Are you sure you used ...FilesDirs() ? And not ...FilesDir()? Did you get two paths? You talk about one path only.

Comment: yep, but it's my PM's request :-)  I have to do this, so i found `DocumentFile` and use this way can write indeed. (I would cut off this function if i were boss = =.)

Comment: Yes i get two paths. What i want is execute write-operation in external sdcard, so i just talked about external sdcard only. Actually it can get two paths.

Comment: And did you try to write on the second path?

Comment: the second path is the external sdcard path. I've already tested file.mkdir cannot create dictionary successfully.